# ¿Como ingresar valor a un select option que es dependiente de uno superior?

Tags: javascript, select

Voy a reformular la pregunta a ver si logro explicarme mejor, pues no consigo la solución.
Tengo un formulario en el que hay dos select option, el primero `"cbx_Autonomias"`  que coge los datos a través de php de una base de datos phpmyAdmin, y después tengo otro `"cbx_Provincia"` que es anidado del primero, funciona perfectamente pues selecciono las opciones y guardo perfectamente en una base de datos (los valores que guardo son los ID), el problema surge cuando quiero recuperar los datos para editarlo y actualizarlo, en el que solo asigna valor al primero como se puede ver en la imagen.

[image: estos son los select]

Código:

Se aprecia que solo recoge el valor el primer select pero he comprobado que no actualiza el estado por eso el problema de no asignar valor al segundo, pues como es anidado la filtración que tiene no corresponde con ninguna opción, y de eso que quede sin valor. Para dar valor tengo que asignar de nuevo el valor manualmente y es entonces cuando el segundo lo detecta y si me deja elegir opción, en fin que no funciona como debe pues al asignar los valores desde la base de datos debería de cogerlo el segundo.

Os pongo la función editar por si alguien puede aporta a la misma la solución, gracias de antemano.

```
function editar(
           //paso los parámetros de BD
          A_3_Autonomia      ,
          A_4_Provincia      ,
){
   //asigno valores a los dos elementos del formulario
  document.getElementById('cbx_autonomias').value = A_3_Autonomia;
  document.getElementById('cbx_Provincia').value = A_4_Provincia; 

  //cambio el nombre del boton por editar
  var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
  boton.innerHTML = 'Editar';

  //ejecuto la función al dar click con los nuevos valores
  boton.onclick = function(){
  var Autonomia_editado = document.getElementById('cbx_autonomias').value;
  var Provincia_editado = document.getElementById('cbx_Provincia') .value;

  return editarParte.update({ //se los paso a las variables para actualizar
       A_3_Autonomia: Autonomia_editado,
       A_4_Provincia: Provincia_editado,
 })
  .then(function(){
   console.log("Document successfully updated!");
   boton.innerHTML = 'Guardar';
   document.getElementById('cbx_autonomias').value = '' ;
   document.getElementById('cbx_Provincia') .value = '' ; 

//cambio de nuevo el nombre del boton        
boton.onclick=function(){
            guardar();
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
      // El documento no existe
      console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
      });
     }
  }
```

Este es el código del html

```
                            <select name="cbx_autonomias" id="cbx_autonomias" class="form-control my-1">
                                <option value="">Seleccione autonomía</option><!--valor y texto select-->
                                <?php while($row = $resultado_autonomia->fetch_assoc()) { ?><!--recorremos resultado consulta-->
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row['id_autonomia']; ?>"><?php echo $row['NombreAutonomias']; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>  <!--valor de los id de la taba phpmyadmin,    texto a mostrar de la tabla phpmyadmin-->
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><!--Campo entrada 1_a-provincia, consulta datos de getProvincias.php-->
                            <select name="cbx_Provincia" id="cbx_Provincia"class="form-control my-1"></select>
                        </td>
```

esta es la consulta que hago a la tabla para autonomía

```
$query = "SELECT id_autonomia, NombreAutonomias FROM Autonomias ORDER BY id_autonomia ASC";//columnas de la tabla Autonomias
    $resultado_autonomia=$mysqli->query($query);
```

Este es el script para realizar la consulta  y poder filtrar Provincias

```
    <script language="javascript">//filtros para los select
            //Selección Autonomías
            $(document).ready(function(){//filtro provincia
                    $("#cbx_autonomias").change(function () {
                        //si detectamos cambio en el select autonomía
                        $("#cbx_autonomias option:selected").each(function () {//get selección valor autonomia
                            id_autonomia = $(this).val();//creamos variable con value de autonomia
                            $.post("includes/getProvincia.php", { id_autonomia: id_autonomia }, function(data){
                                //enviamos post a archivo, para buscar igualdad, pasando parametro de variable
                                $("#cbx_Provincia").html(data);//asignamos valor filtrado a selec provincia
                            });            
                        });
                    })
            });

</script>
```

y este ultimo es la conexión y consulta para Provincias

```
<?php
    require ('../conexion.php'); //recibimos conexión de para la base de datos phpmyadmin

    $id_autonomia = $_POST['id_autonomia'];/*recibimos datos de la variable $POST, de script
    que se encuentra en primer lugar de la cabecera del archivo index asignado valor a variable
    para realizar la consulta como parámetro*/
    /*Consulta de donde selecionamos dos columnas de la tabal provincia  y con filtro que sea igual 
    a la variable $id_autonomia ordenando por Nombre de la Provincia*/
    $queryM = "SELECT id_provincia, NombreProvincias FROM Provincias WHERE autonomia_id = '$id_autonomia' ORDER BY NombreProvincias";
    $resultadoP = $mysqli->query($queryM);//resultado de la consulta

    $html= "<option value=''>Seleccionar provincia</option>";

    while($rowM = $resultadoP->fetch_assoc()){//recorremos el parámetro de la consulta 
        $html.= "<option value='".$rowM['id_provincia']."'>".$rowM['NombreProvincias']."</option>";
    }

    echo $html;
?>
```

Pues bien todo funciona perfectamente menos cuando tomo los datos para actualizar que no da valor al select anidado (provincias)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede comprobar en esta prueba autonomia devuelve valor de su select y en cambio el de provincia no devuelve nada, pues es dependiente de autonomia, creo que el problema esta aqui, pues si autonomía no detecta cambio de estado el select provincia no puede ejecutar su acción para filtrar datos con lo cual en las opciones no tiene valor a elegir, y por eso no puedo asignar el valor que rescato de la tabla para editarlos

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código HTML de tus select?

Comment: Gracias Diego por el interés mostrado, espero que me puedas ayudar, estoy con este nudo y no avanzo.

Comment: Si te esta devolviendo correctamente la información que debe ir en el segundo select? o no existe tal información?

Comment: No, el de provincia no devuelve nada y en cambio el de autonomía si, pero el de provincia es dependiente de autonomia, si autonomia no detecta cambio la filtración en el de provincia es null, creo que ahí esta el problema, no puede asignar un valor que no tiene en sus opciones, pongo imagenes de la prueba que he realizado